# How to access each element of a Vector<3> from the TooN library?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a Vector<3> (of TooN.h library).
This should be a vector of a three elements (int), right?
How can I access to each int value?

I'd like to do something like:

```
#include <TooN/TooN.h>    

// Create a vector initialised to [1 2 3];
Vector<3> v = makeVector(1, 2, 3);

//this is wrong!
int a = v.x; //a=1
int b = v.y; //b=2
int c = v.z; //c=3
```

Comment: why not `v[0]`, `v[1]`, ...?

Comment: there is no `Vector` in c++. Maybe you meant `std::vector` ? Please post real code, preferably a [mcve]

Comment: `Vector` is your custom data structure. Show its code.

Comment: @tobi303 the question clearly says it is from TooN.h library

Comment: @M.M yep I overlooked that on the first read

Comment: @tobi303 Vector<3> is from TooN.h library

Comment: my tip: read the docs. It took me ~5 seconds to find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/toon/html-user/structTooN_1_1Vector.html)  you access the elements as `v[0]`, `v[1]`, `v[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

access an element of the vector

can be used as an l-value `i.e`

```
 Vector<3> v;
 v[0] = 10;
```

Source : [TooN: Vector Documentation](https://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/toon/html-user/structTooN_1_1Vector.html)